# Delete elements in array, which are duplicated and follow each other sequentially

Tags: javascript

I have an array which sometimes has duplicated elements follow each other sequentially. For example:

```
["<app-builder-navbar></app-builder-navbar>",
 "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
 "<app-builder-hero></app-builder-hero>",
 "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
 "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
 "<app-builder-footer></app-builder-footer>"]
```

I want to delete all instances where duplicated elements (namely `<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>`) follow each other sequentially. So the above, would end up looking like this:

```
["<app-builder-navbar></app-builder-navbar>",
 "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
 "<app-builder-hero></app-builder-hero>",
 "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
 "<app-builder-footer></app-builder-footer>"]
```

My approach below seems to work somewhat but deletes all the `<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>` items on occasion or produces an erratic result set.

```
function deleteDuplicatePlaceholders(components) {
  for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < components.length; j++) {
      if (components[i] === '<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>' &&
        components[j] === '<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>') {
        components.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to delete duplicate and sequential instances of just these: `<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>`? Or do you want to delete any consecutive values?

Comment: Yup, only `<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>` for the time being but with scope to delete any other consecutive values later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty cleanly done with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The idea is to compare the current element against its predecessor and omit it from the result if they match. Use caution for the edge case where `a` contains `undefined` (adding `a.slice(1)` can help).

```js
const dedupeAdjacent = a => a.filter((e, i) => e !== a[i-1]);

const placeholders = [
  "<app-builder-navbar></app-builder-navbar>",
  "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
  "<app-builder-hero></app-builder-hero>",
  "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
  "<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>",
  "<app-builder-footer></app-builder-footer>"
];

console.log(dedupeAdjacent(placeholders));
```

If you need to limit the deduping behavior to one element (or a set of elements), I'd pass it in as a parameter to keep the function reusable.

```js
const dedupeAdjacent = (a, target) => 
  a.filter((e, i) => e !== a[i-1] || e !== target)
;

const placeholders = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3];
console.log(dedupeAdjacent(placeholders, 1));
```

Finally, here it is against an array of target elements. If you expect a huge number of `targets` or a large input, build a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), otherwise just use `includes` to avoid the heap allocation. You could also cache the set in the caller and pass it in, but this is a bit burdensome.

```js
const dedupeAdjacent = (a, targets) => 
  a.filter((e, i) => e !== a[i-1] || !targets.includes(e))
;

const dedupeAdjacentWithLotsOfTargets = (a, targets) => {
  targets = new Set(targets); // this step is expensive
  return a.filter((e, i) => e !== a[i-1] || !targets.has(e));
};

const placeholders = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3];
console.log(dedupeAdjacent(placeholders, [1, 3]));
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I make it work with particular array items ony i.e. deduping matches of `<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>` specifically.

Comment: Done. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Array.filter` as mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.

The filter function can just check if current element is same as previous element and any other condition that you might want.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to turn it into a Set and then back into an Array:

```
const placeholders = Array.from(new Set([someDuplicatedValues]));
```

Any duplicated values will be omitted, since Sets only contain unique values.

Comment: Good idea, but this doesn't handle adjacent elements correctly. OP wants `"<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>"` to appear twice in the result.